# How can I perform this replacement

Tags: replacement

```
(a[1]^2 + a[2]^2 + a[3]^2) /. {{a[1], a[2], a[3]} -> Normalize[{1, 2, 3}]}
```

I would like to replace each `a[i]` accordingly.

Comment: you mean `(a[1]^2 + a[2]^2 + a[3]^2) /. a[i_] :> Normalize[a[i]]`?

Comment: .. or `(a[1]^2 + a[2]^2 + a[3]^2) /. 
 Thread[{a[1], a[2], a[3]} -> Normalize[{1, 2, 3}]]` ?

Comment: @kglr Thank you.

Comment: Philip, my pleasure. By _to replace each a[i] accordingly_, do you mean `a[i_] :> Normalize[a[i]]` or `Thread[{a[1], a[2], a[3]} -> Normalize[{1, 2, 3}]]`?

Comment: @kglr I needed the latter.

Answer (score 3):

```
(a[1]^2 + a[2]^2 + a[3]^2) /. Thread[{a[1], a[2], a[3]} -> Normalize[{1, 2, 3}]]
```

> 1